# Is it possible to list item views in a list horizontally?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Could I use a list to accept a list of widgets and then position them horizontally, maybe inside of a Row? I know a grid could do it but for only 3 items (like in the picture above) I'm wondering if there is a more suitable widget for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use `ListView.builder`, and set scrol direction to `horizontal`. You don't have to use a row.